# How to reference .properties value on application.conf

Tags: java, akka, akka-remote-actor

I have an J2EE app which uses a custom actor system and I need to externalize some custom configurations.

Is there a way to do this? Since the `application.conf` is always on the classpath is there anyway I can load an external `custom.properties` file and use it like below

```
ActorSystem.akka.remote.netty.hostname = "${custom.ip}"
ActorSystem.akka.remote.netty.port = "${custom.port}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your constraints are, but in principle you have several options:

1. You can provide *hardcoded configuration* to your actor system, when you create it, like this:

   ```
   Map configMap = new HashMap();
   configMap.put("akka.remote.netty.hostname", custom.ip);
   configMap.put("akka.remote.netty.port", custom.port);

   Config config = ConfigFactory.parseMap(configMap).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());
   ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ActorSystem", config);
   ```
2. you can load you custom config file instead of `application.conf` either through code: `ConfigFactory.load("custom.conf")` or by setting a system property `-Dconfig.resource=custom.conf` and include `application.conf` in your `custom.conf`, like this:

   ```
   include "application"
   akka.remote.netty.hostname = "custom-ip"
   akka.remote.netty.port = "custom-port"
   ```
3. You could also provide the custom-port and ip through system properties and use defaults, if they are not defined. In that case the `application.conf` would look like this:

   ```
   akka.remote.netty.hostname = "default-ip"
   akka.remote.netty.port = "default-port"
   akka.remote.netty.hostname = "${?custom.ip}"
   akka.remote.netty.port = "${?custom.port}"
   ```
4. Or you can include `custom.properties` in your `application.conf` file. If the `custom.properties` does not exist if will silently be ignored. `application.conf`:

   ```
   akka.remote.netty.hostname = "default-ip"
   akka.remote.netty.port = "default-port"
   include "custom"
   ```

   `custom.properties`:

   ```
   akka.remote.netty.hostname = "custom-ip"
   akka.remote.netty.port = "custom-port"
   ```

Comment: thanks, what I want to do is load these variables from JNDI Enviroment variables throuhg java:comp/env?

Comment: I would assume in that case you could go with alternative 1: Read them from JNDI and provide them to your akka-system programmatically.

Comment: @VolkerStampa and can you just auto-magicaly read properties from System.properties? as if you want to do it manually you need to know which properties to ready from System.getProperty(); I would like to use application.conf from jar and override/add configuration when I start jar with akka app.

Comment: @kamiseq Not exactly sure what you mean. But isn't alternative 3 what you need? You specify the default in your application.conf from the jar and you can override these defaults with defining system-properties on command line.

Comment: @VolkerStampa hi, thanks for answering. ok so I need to change application.cong structure (from tree to list of properties) and then if any property will be added to application with -Dakka.remote.netty.hostname=other akka will use such "other" value instead of "default-ip"? right?

Comment: @kamiseq Sorry for the late answer. You do not have to change the structure of your file. If your `application.conf` uses a tree-structure, you can still overwrite with system properties by defining the path from the root-node. I.e. with `root { path { leaf = "v" } }` you can still overwrite with `root.path.leaf`.